# nmcli and nmtui both don't allow me to modify a connection. Settings plugin does not support modifying connections

Tags: nmcli

```
nmcli con mod "Ifupdown (eth0)" ipv4.addresses 192.168.50.188/24
```

Error: Failed to modify connection 'Ifupdown (eth0)': failed to update connection: settings plugin does not support modifying connections

Answer (score 0):

Same here on Debian 11 and network-manager-1.30.0-2. Can't modify any connection properties:

```
#  nmcli c m "Ifupdown (eth0)" 802-3-ethernet.wake-on-lan magic 
Error: Failed to modify connection 'Ifupdown (eth0)': failed to update connection: settings plugin does not support modifying connections
```

Installed the system using cloud init and a generic Debian cloud image. Got it to work after

1. commenting out `source-directory /run/network/interfaces.d` in `/etc/network/interfaces`
2. renaming or deleting `/etc/udev/rules.d/75-cloud-ifupdown.rules` in order to prevent the helper script (`/etc/network/cloud-ifupdown-helper`) being run.

After rebooting the system, `Ifupdown (eth0)` got renamed to `Wired connection 1`. I could change connection properties then.

Of course, this is only a valid solution if you don't need the cloud init stuff after finishing system setup.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have l2 connection to vm beforehand!

I'm running a Debian 11 vm onprem and editing out all config except the following from `/etc/network/interfaces` fixed the same issue for me

```
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address {n.n.n.n}{/nn}
    gateway {n.n.n.n}
    dns-nameservers {n.n.n.n}{n.n.n.n}
    dns-search example.com
```

To avoid having to restart you can run

```
systemctl restart NetworkManager networking
```